# Stored Program Computer in modern computing

Tags: cpu-architecture

I was given this exact question on a quiz.

Question

[image]

Answer

[image]

Does the question make any sense? My understanding is that the OS schedules a process and manages what instructions it needs the processor to execute next. This is because the OS is liable to pull all sorts of memory management tricks, especially in main memory where fragmentation is a way of life. I remember that there is supposed to be a special register on the processor called the program counter. In light of the scheduler and memory management done by the OS I have trouble figuring out the purpose of this register unless it is just for the OS. Is the concept of the Stored Program Computer really relevant to how a modern computer operates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardware fetches machine code from main memory, at the address in the program counter (which increments on its own as instructions execute, or is modified by executing a jump or call instruction).

Software has to load the code into RAM (main memory) and start the process with its program counter pointing into that memory.

And yes, if the OS wants to page that memory out to disk (or lazily load it in the first place), hardware will trigger a page fault when the CPU tries to fetch code from an unmapped page.

But no, the OS does *not* feed instructions to the CPU one at a time.

(Unless you're debugging a program by putting the CPU into "single step" mode when returning to user-space for that process, so it traps after executing one instruction.  Like x86's trap flag, for example.  Some ISAs only have software breakpoints, not HW support for single stepping.)

But anyway, the OS itself is made up of machine code that runs *on* the CPU.  CPU hardware knows how to fetch and execute instructions from memory.  An OS is just a fancy program that can load and manage other programs.  (Remember, in a von Neumann architecture, code is data.)

Answer (score 1):

Even the OS has to depend on the processing architecture. Memory today often is virtualized. That means the memory location seen by the program is not the real physical location, but is indirected by one or more tables describing the actual location and some attributes (e.g. read/write/execute allowed or not) for memory accesses. If the accessed virtual memory has not been loaded into main memory (these tables say so), an exception is generated, and the address of an exception handler is loaded into the program counter. This exception handler is by the OS and resides in main memory. So the program counter is quite relevant with today's computers, but the next instruction can be changed by exceptions (exceptions are also called for thread or process switching in preemptive multitasking systems) on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the question make any sense?

Yes.  It makes sense to me.  It is a bit imprecise, but the meanings of each of the alternatives are sufficiently distinct to be able to say that D) is the best answer.

<sup>(In theory, you could create a von Neumann computer which was able to execute instructions out of secondary storage, registers or even the internet ... but it would be highly impractical for various reasons.)</sup>

> My understanding is that the OS schedules a process and manages what instructions it needs the processor to execute next. This is because the OS is liable to pull all sorts of memory management tricks, especially in main memory where fragmentation is a way of life.

Fragmentation of main memory is not actually relevant.  A modern machine uses special hardware (and page tables) to deal with that.  From the perspective of executing code (application or kernel) this is all hidden.  The code uses virtual addresses, and the hardware maps them to physical addresses.  (This is even true when dealing with page faults, though special care will be taken to ensure that the code and page table entries for the page fault handler are in RAM pages that are never swapped out.)

> I remember that there is supposed to be a special register on the processor called the program counter. In light of the scheduler and memory management done by the OS I have trouble figuring out the purpose of this register unless it is just for the OS.

The PC is fundamental.  It contains the virtual memory address of the next instruction that the CPU is to execute.  For application code AND for OS kernel code.  When you switch between the application and kernel code, the value in the PC is updated as part of the *context switch*.

> Is the concept of the Stored Program Computer really relevant to how a modern computer operates?

Yes.  Unless you are working on a special custom machine where (say) the program has been transformed into custom silicon.